# OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long when deploying Flask project with BIGQUERY_KEY_PATH on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, filenames, oserror

I have a Flask project that I am deploying to a Heroku server. I use a Config Var to setup a variable called BIGQUERY_KEY_PATH (.json key to a Service Account on my BigQuery database).

I have set up the file with the following command:

```
heroku config:set BIGQUERY_KEY_PATH="$(cat /path/to/file/bq_key.json)" --app app_name
```

But when running the app I get:

```
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long
```

With the content of the file shown in the rest of the error message as a string.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have not found a solution because I am not very familar with Heroku

Comment: `$(cat file)` will output the file **contents**.  Surely that's not what you want?

Comment: Presumably `BIGQUERY_KEY_PATH` is supposed to just be the _full pathname_ to the file, not its _contents_...

Comment: @JohnGordon, no indeed I am only trying to add the file to the server so that when the code is run, the server with fetch the specific file and use it in the codebase. I might be completely wrong in my approach (just started developping). Thank you for your comments, If you have  a recommendation on what to do, I would be grateful.

Comment: I already said what to do.  Set `BIGQUERY_KEY_PATH` to the file _path_, not its _contents_.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to store the file in my repository which is why I am trying to add it as a server variable

Comment: As far as I know, you _must_ provide the credentials as a json file.  If you don't want to store the file in the repository, then you might need an intermediate step in your build procedure that copies the local json key file into the deployment.  (I don't know anything about Heroku or BigQuery, so I can't give you a detailed answer on how to do that.)  Good luck!